# Bind attribute like maxlength on handlebars input helper

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

My fields constraints are duplicate on server and client side, and I don't like it..

For now I have something like:

```
{{input type="text" value=firstname maxlength=50}}
```

Server side I generate js to make my domain classes constraints available to client side, the result would be for example:

```
var CONSTRAINTS = {
   "person.firstname.maxlength" : 50,
   "person.lastname.maxlength" : 70
};
```

What is the best way to bind these values ?

Answer (score 1):

You could try to do it in your App.PersonController:

```
App.PersonController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
  firstNameLength:CONSTRAINTS['person.firstname.maxlength'],
  lastNameLength:CONSTRAINTS['person.lastname.maxlength']
});
```

Then in your template it would just be:

```
{{input type="text" value=firstname maxlength=firstNameLength}}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot for the suggestion. I didn't know it was possible to simply give maxlength a property name like you did. However it feels like an unnecessary step, and also my controllers would cluttered with lots of additional properties.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up altering my generated constraints:

```
var CONSTRAINTS = {
    Person: {
        firstName: {
            maxlength: 50
        },
        lastName: {
            maxlength: 70
        },            
    }
};
```

And use it directly in my template:

```
{{input type="text" value=firstname maxlength=CONSTRAINTS.Person.firstName.maxlength}}
```